# Simple semi-compile-time 'event-bus' in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to hide serious design flaws in my application behind event bus :)
I created template class with static  event handlers holder like this:

```
template<typename ET>
class EventHandler;

template<typename ET>
class EventBus {
public:
    static std::vector<EventHandler<ET>*> handlers;
};
template<typename ET>
std::vector<EventHandler<ET>*> EventBus<ET>::handlers = std::vector<EventHandler<ET>*>();
```

Next part of my 'event-bus' is template class for event handler:

```
template<typename ET>
class EventHandler {
public:
    EventHandler() {
        EventBus<ET>::handlers.emplace_back(this);
    }
    ~EventHandler() {
        auto &handlers=EventBus<ET>::handlers;
        handlers.erase(std::remove(handlers.begin(), handlers.end(), this), handlers.end());
    }
    virtual void handle_event(ET &event) = 0;
};
```

Here is a complete code with example usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

template<typename ET>
class EventHandler;

template<typename ET>
class EventBus {
public:
    static std::vector<EventHandler<ET>*> handlers;
};
template<typename ET>
std::vector<EventHandler<ET>*> EventBus<ET>::handlers = std::vector<EventHandler<ET>*>();

template<typename ET>
class EventHandler {
public:
    EventHandler() {
        EventBus<ET>::handlers.emplace_back(this);
    }
    ~EventHandler() {
        auto &handlers=EventBus<ET>::handlers;
        handlers.erase(std::remove(handlers.begin(), handlers.end(), this), handlers.end());
    }
    virtual void handle_event(ET &event) = 0;
};

template<typename ET>
void publish(ET &event) {
    for(auto handler : EventBus<ET>::handlers) {
        handler->handle_event(event);
    }
}

class MyClass: public EventHandler<int>, public EventHandler<std::string> {
public:
    void handle_event(int &event) override {
        std::cout << "handling int event" << std::endl;
    }

    void handle_event(std::string &event) override {
        std::cout << "handling std::string event" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    int eventData = 1;
    MyClass eventHandler2;
    std::string stringEventData = "hello, world";
    {
        MyClass eventHandler;
        publish(eventData);
        publish(stringEventData);
    }
    publish(eventData);
    publish(stringEventData);
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So the question is - is there some chance that I will have issues with resolving correct `handle_event` method based on event type with mulptiple inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any issues resolving the `handle_event` overload with the given `publish()` function, because only one `handle_event` member function is actually visible in this function: the type being invoked on is `EventHandler<ET>`, which only knows about `handle_event(ET&)` (whatever `ET` happens to be).

For example, if `ET` is `int`, this function doesn't even see the `handle_event(std::string&)` overload because that overload isn't part of the `EventHandler<int>` interface.